# ArcGIS points to polygons: includes all points in source not just those in layer

Tags: arcgis, arcmap

I'm new to ArcGIS and I'm bumbling through teaching myself. I am trying to count how many points are within a number of defined polygons. I have a large number of points, but I only want to count a subset. Here is how I tried to achieve this and failed.

In the attribute table for my points, there is a field called **Type** and I only want those of type **C**. So, I select these points and created a new layer that comprised of only **C** points. Then, I go to my polygon layer and select **Joins and Relates > Join...**. Next, I select **Join data from another layer based on spatial location** and select the layer containing only **C** type points. I choose **Sum** to count all the points and create a shape file.

This counts the points that fall in the polygons, but it counts **all** points and not just type **C**. Somehow it's including the original source rather than just those in the layer I created. Why is this the case and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your method is good in terms of using the Join and Related approach. Once you have done that, to count the number of points of a certain type:

1. Open the attribute table of the layer and right-click on the Type field.
2. Leave "Select a field..." as Type and don't tick any other fields; hit OK.
3. Under Table of Contents panel choose List by Source, find the output table (which ArcMap will create with a name like "Sum_Output_1") and right-click to open the table. The table should have a field called Type with a count for each kind of point.

Does that work?

-nick

Answer (score 0):

In ArcMAP there is some sort of connection between the original layer and the layer created from a selection of the original layer. If you export the layer you created from selection as a new shapefile/feature class and then add it to the map your join method should return a count that is strictly from your newly added "C" layer and not your original layer.

That said, there is a better way to do this, in my opinion: "Select by Location..."

Using your original layer you can go to the "Selection" tab on your main menu and choose "Select By Location..." and enter your criteria in the pop-up. For "Target layer(s)" select your original layer. For "Source layer" select your defined polygons layer. In the "Spatial selection method for target layer feature(s)" dropdown select "are within the source layer feature" and click OK. In your original layer attribute table all your points within the polygons will be selected. At the bottom of your attribute table click the "Show selected records" button. Right click your "Type" column and sort ascending. Highlight your "C" values and click the "Reselect Highlighted" button at the top of your table. You now have a count down at the bottom of the table of just C points that were selected from within your polygons.

Using this method there is no new layer creation, no joins, no extra files to manage. And of course at the end of this method you have the option to export your selected data as it's own layer if you wish.